# SCIP with Cplex

Tags: cplex, scip

I have a problem running scip with cplex! when I run "make LPS=cpx ZIMPL=false", I got the following error:
make LPS=cpx ZIMPL=false
make: *** No rule to make target `~/scipoptsuite-3.0.2/scip-3.0.2/lib/liblpicpx.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a', needed by`bin/vrp.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.cpx'.  Stop.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please be more specific what the second part of your question means, don't you succeed creating soft links? Following the answers below, soft link creation should not be an issue, because SCIP does this for you. Please mark an answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to build the VRP example of SCIP. Before you can do this, you need to build SCIP itself with the exact same options, in particular also with CPLEX as LP solver. You can even do this from the VRP example directory by using the Makefile target 'scip', i.e., make LPS=cpx ZIMPL=false scip.

Comment: I run "make LPS=cpx ZIMPL=false" plus adding the cplex libraries and include files location, but I got the following error!

Comment: > generating library lib/libobjscip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `lib/cpxinc/cplex.h', needed by `obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/lpi/lpi_cpx.o'.  Stop.

Comment: okay, a weird thing happened, I can create the softlinks on the old version of scip, "scipoptsuite-3.0.2", but on new version(scipoptsuite-3.1.0), the above steps lead to error (No rule to make target lib/cpxinc/cplex.h', needed by obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/lpi/lpi_cpx.o'. Stop)!!!

Comment: Do you use the `scip`-target as suggested by Gerald for making the VRP-example, or have you switched to the SCIP directory? Make sure you use absolute paths for the soft-links.

Comment: I did not use the absolute paths, it is now working! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you try to compile the VRP-example of SCIP before ever compiling the main SCIP. You need to first compile the main SCIP, i.e., go to the main SCIP-directory and run your 
make-command. This will create the necessary library `liblpicpx.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.a`, which the example depends on.
Note that the `make`-command automatically asks you for the include and library paths. If not, you can force this behaviour by calling

```
make LPS=cpx ZIMPL=false links
```

More Makefile options are explained in the [documentation](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/MAKE.php).